# SQLite3: database not being saved

Tags: database, cocoa, macos, sqlite, save

I'm creating a Mac app which will save some data to a SQLite database. The problem is: when I close the database and open it again, the data is not there. Here's my code:

```
NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO people(name, artist, id, album, location, cover) VALUES('%@', '%@', %d, '%@', '%@', '%@');", name, artist, ID, album, path, cover];

 sqlite3 *database = NULL;      
 sqlite3_open([[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"db" ofType:@"database"]
   cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], &database);  

 sqlite3_stmt *statement;       
 sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people(name TEXT, id INT, artist TEXT, album TEXT, cover TEXT, location TEXT);", -1, &statement, NULL);   
 sqlite3_step(statement);
 sqlite3_finalize(statement);       
 sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], -1, &statement, NULL);   
 sqlite3_step(statement);
 sqlite3_finalize(statement);

 statement = NULL;
 sqlite3_close(database);
```

Comment: What about putting some error handling in there? You're not checking any of those function calls, and they pretty much all can fail.

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to save your database to the application bundle? That’s not the recommended location.

Comment: I did the check and everything seems to be working fine. I also noticed that when I created a new database on the Application Support directory, I was able to save data to it. But, then when I opened it again, I wasn't able to save any data to it :(

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code to check your insert:

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
char *errmsg;
const char *sql = [isql cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"SQL Warning: Erro ao executar a instrução '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    sqlite3_reset(stmt);
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    return;
}

if(!sqlite3_exec(database, sql, nil, &stmt, &errmsg) == SQLITE_OK) NSLog(@"SQL Warning: '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

sqlite3_reset(stmt);
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```